# shell script - replace variables from array

Tags: shell, replace

A script yields the following output:

```
MyProgram down : Computer7 Network 31 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:56:06.22
MyProgram up   : Computer7 Network 31 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.22
MyProgram down : Computer7 Network 32 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram down : Computer8 Network 32 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram up   : Computer7 Network 32 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram up   : Computer8 Network 32 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram down : Computer8 Network 19 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:28.46
MyProgram up   : Computer8 Network 19 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:29.46
```

However, I need to batch-replace certain strings, e.g.

```
Computer7 Network 31 = 'Harbor1'
Computer7 Network 32 = 'Matrix7'
Computer8 Network 19 = 'Romulos1'
Computer8 Network 32 = 'Synergy20'
...
```

What's a brief and performant solution to achieve the following output?

```
MyProgram down : Harbor1 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:56:06.22
MyProgram up   : Harbor1 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.22
MyProgram down : Matrix7 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram down : Synergy20 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram up   : Matrix7 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram up   : Synergy20 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram down : Romulos1 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:28.46
MyProgram up   : Romulos1 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:29.46
```

After mapping the new output how i can group down/up event of the same program like:

```
MyProgram down/up : Harbor1 N_ID 1 Down 14:56:06.22 - Up 14:57:06.22 on 11-Apr-2014
MyProgram down/up : Matrix7 N_ID 1 Down 14:57:06.40 - Up 14:57:06.43 on 11-Apr-2014
MyProgram down/up : Synergy20 N_ID 2 Down 14:57:06.40 - Up 14:57:06.43 on 11-Apr-2014
MyProgram down/up : Romulos1 N_ID 2 Down 01:59:28.46 - Up 01:59:29.46 on 12-Apr-2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed -f`:

```
$ cat mappings
s/Computer7 Network 31/Harbor1/
s/Computer7 Network 32/Matrix7/
s/Computer8 Network 19/Romulos1/
s/Computer8 Network 32/Synergy20/

$ sed -f mappings file
MyProgram down : Harbor1 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:56:06.22
MyProgram up   : Harbor1 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.22
MyProgram down : Matrix7 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram down : Synergy20 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram up   : Matrix7 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram up   : Synergy20 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram down : Romulos1 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:28.46
MyProgram up   : Romulos1 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:29.46
```

If you find preparing the mapping file with `sed` expressions cumbersome you can use an arbitrary format and use an additional `sed` and [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to prepare the input for `-f` , e.g.:

```
$ cat mappings
Computer7 Network 31=Harbor1
Computer7 Network 32=Matrix7
Computer8 Network 19=Romulos1
Computer8 Network 32=Synergy20

$ sed -f <(sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#s/\1/\2/#g' mappings) file
MyProgram down : Harbor1 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:56:06.22
MyProgram up   : Harbor1 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.22
MyProgram down : Matrix7 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram down : Synergy20 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.40
MyProgram up   : Matrix7 N_ID 1 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram up   : Synergy20 N_ID 2 at : 11-Apr-2014 14:57:06.43
MyProgram down : Romulos1 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:28.46
MyProgram up   : Romulos1 N_ID 2 at : 12-Apr-2014 01:59:29.46
```